How should I go about retrieving the date of when a question became/was no longer hot with SEDE?
I am currently making a SEDE query to determine which questions from a specific user have made it onto the Hot Network Questions list and when. While I can get the specific questions, I am unable to figure out how to get the date when those questions became/were no longer a Hot Network Question.
From this answer, I have knowledge of how to get questions that were on the HNQ list for a specific user (this can be done by searching for questions with PostTypeHistoryId=52 that were asked by a certain user), but am unable to find anything on how to find when said questions hit/disappeared from the HNQ list, despite searching through the hot-questions and data-explorer tags. (along with doing a few Google searches)
This is what I currently have:
DECLARE @UserId INT = ##UserId##
SELECT DISTINCT p.Id AS [Post Link], p.PostTypeId, u.DisplayName AS [User Link], p.CreationDate
FROM Posts p
JOIN Users u ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
JOIN PostHistory ph ON p.Id = ph.PostId
WHERE (OwnerUserId = @UserId) AND (ph.PostHistoryTypeId = 52)
ORDER BY p.Id ASC

My question is: How should I go about extending my code as to include the times for which a question became/was no longer hot with SEDE, or is there a resource that I could use on how to do this?

@testing-ma-lady Yes, me. (testing on Puzzling.SE - I have 20 HNQs there)

SEDE doesn't record the moment the question is no longer on the Hot Network Questions list, unless that happens because a moderator removed it (in that case, you will find a Post History with type 53). In the vast majority of the cases, the question is no longer on the list because it isn't in the top 100 anymore; other common reasons are the question being closed, or too long in the list (there's a 72 hours maximum).
I have a script which downloads the HNQ every 3 minutes since 2018, and from the results you could determine when a particular question no longer appeared on the list. I used to publish the results of it once in a while, but that paused due to other pressing matters. I might do it again in 6-8 weeks ...
